# prolog rule that takes as input a list of integers and returns “yes” if the list’s elements are all equal, otherwise returns “no”

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have a list `[1, 1, 1, 1]`. I need a way to check IF every element within this list are all equal return yes otherwise return no
without using any of the built-in predicates. 
`list(3,3)`-->> yes , `list(3,3,6)`-->> no 
I came up with this rule but it doesn't work

```
equal([E1,E2|T]):- E1=:=E2,
       equal([E2,E3|T]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `E3` appeared out of nowhere.  I think you want

```
equal([]).
equal([X]).
equal([E1,E2|T]) :-
    E1 =:= E2,
    equal([E2|T]).
```

Comment: You beat me by 10 sec :). The base case is actually `equal([X]).` i.e. one element

Comment: To a mathematician, an empty set has all its elements equal.  The exact definition might depend on the program's domain / needs.

Comment: I don't disagree that if we reached `equal([]).` it wouldn't be true, but in your implementation, you don't have a case for one element. In this sense, since `equal([]).` can never be reached its just there to state an idea.

Comment: @false: The `=:=` operator requires numeric terms.

Comment: @aschepter: So you want that `equal([1+1,2])` is true as well? At least I cannot read anything to that end from OP's statement.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, such a predicate is defined using general equality, not arithmetic equality:

```
equal(Xs) :-
   maplist(=(_), Xs).
```

Is probably the most insightful definition. This uses `maplist/2` commonly defined as

```
maplist(_, []).
maplist(C, [E|Es]) :-
   call(C, E),
   maplist(C, Es).
```

Otherwise:

```
equal(Xs) :-
   equals_to(Xs,_).

equals_to([], _).
equals_to([E|Es], E) :-
   equals_to(Es, E).
```